# Query a table with linked objects as columns

Tags: postgresql

Title of the question is not clear, I'll try to describe it.

In my model I have the following :

A Network object includes Lines, and a Line object includes Routes (this is for public transportation).

Now I have a *Subscription* table where I handle user subscriptions for travelling on Networks, Lines or Routes :

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Network ║ Line ║ Route ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ A  ║       1 ║ 6    ║ 12    ║
║ B  ║       2 ║ 3    ║ NULL  ║
║ C  ║       1 ║ NULL ║ NULL  ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

That means :

- Subscription A is valid only on route 12
- Subscription B is valid on all routes of line 3
- Subscriptions C is valid on all routes of network 1.

I need to get all subscriptions allowed on route#12, i.e. I need to fetch first and third row.

What kind of request would allow me to do so please ?

In the end I'll be doing this in Java with JPQL, but I'd like to understand how to do it in plain SQL first.

[Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fec4/2) in case anyone is willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way of writing this Query but this should do the trick.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ((Line IN (SELECT DISTINCT
    LINE
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Route] = 12)
AND [Rout] IS NULL)
OR [Route] = 12)
OR (
Network IN (SELECT DISTINCT
    Network
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Route] = 12)
AND (LINE IS NULL
OR LINE IN (SELECT DISTINCT
    LINE
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Route] = 12)
))
```

You can change those where conditions to joins. As you can see, its performing 3 select statements in `IN` Clause (one of which is a repetition) which may affect performance. Something like:

```
SELECT
    Main.*
FROM Subscription as Main
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscription as Lines ON Lines.[Route] = 12
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscription as Networks ON Networks.[Route] = 12
WHERE 
    Main.[Route] = 12
    OR (Main.Line = Lines.Line and Main.Route IS NULL)
    OR (Main.Network = Networks.Network AND (Main.Line IS NULL OR Main.Line = Lines.Line ))
```